# Can i refrence a cell in a query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to get all results from sheet 2 where colum A contains the value of cell A24 in current sheet.

=QUERY('SHEET2'!1:997, "select B where A contains A24")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `A24` you would use `'"&A24&"'`